# Unit Testing Exceptions thrown by Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, exception, in-memory-database

I am using the in Memory database in order to unit test methods that use the Entity Framework Core.

I set up the database context as follows:

```
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase();

var context = new DatabaseContext(builder.Options);
var databaseElements = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => new DatabaseElement
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = "Name of Element"
    });
    context.DatabaseElements.AddRange(databaseElements);
    context.SaveChanges();
    _databaseContext = context;
...
```

I use this database context for the tests.
This worked fine.

Is it possible to use this in order to throw Entity Framework exceptions?

It would for example be great if I could test if my method handels those exceptions as excpected (e.g. there is no Connection to the database).

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I am expecting exceptions in my test (if for example I exceed string length), but they are never thrown.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution for this yet. I am using a separate class for data access now and use moq to throw an exception. This is only a workaround, thought.